# How do I access the file importing my module from within my module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-module

If I have two files:

```
# somedir/file_a.py

print(f"I was imported from {file_importing_me}")

def foo():
    pass
```

and

```
# anotherdir/file_b.py

from somedir.file_a import foo

foo()
```

How can I make it work? Access at least the filename of the script which is importing my module?

Comment: I suspect you probably cannot, the better approach would be to pass the name of the file to whatever function or class you are creating in that file and exposing the file name that way.

Comment: Maybe you can use   "traceback.extract_tb" and find the appropriate trace entry with the file path but this is really ugly.